# Inequality for classifiers

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

This is from "A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition". Namely, why is this inequality true?

---

The inequality:

[image: Inequality]

---

I have included the relevant information below.

Page 69:

[image: Page 69]

---

Page 70:

[image: Page 70]

---

Page 65, AKA the lemmas:

[image: Page 65, AKA the lemmas]

---

This is where $\Psi$ is defined:

[image: This is where Psi is defined.]

Comment: No those were for the inequalities that came after.

Comment: Lolz why the downvote. I understand the inequalities that came after what I posted. Im asking for the reasoning for the specific inequality in the picture above. It does not follow from Lemma 5.2 or 5.4. You are not missing any information there.

Comment: Included the extra information.

Comment: You are asking for an answer but you are not bothered to ask clearly the question. I have to go and click on different links or find a paper, try to understand what it is about in order to answer your question. Why would I do that?

Comment: You don't have to answer it lolz. No one is obligating you to do that.

Comment: Plus the inequality is purely a reasoning question. The functions are defined on the pages I gave you. I don't know what inequalities they're using from probability theory to get that.

Comment: Plus the pages aren't displaying cause my rating is too low. They won't let it display on this post.

Comment: Figured out the reasoning.